# Acer chromebook not booting ubuntu

Tags: boot, acer

I installed ubuntu on My Acer c7 Chromebook by using the command,

```
wget http://goo.gl/tnyga; sudo bash tnyga
```

It was working fine, but after a few days it boots in Chrome Os and unable to go back to Ubuntu. I tried so many commands like;

```
sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda
```

Then I try to change the priority of the keren, but no changes.

So can any one suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reinstall Ubuntu with crouton. You can get an insallation tutorial here: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343